# Insert into MySQL table with select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

My MySQL table has three columns and ten rows:

```
ID     NAME     ParentID
1    Parent #1    NULL
2    Child #1      1
3    Child #1      1 
4    Child #1      1
5    Child #1      2
6    Child #1      2
7    Child #1      3
8    Child #1      3
9    Child #1      3
10   Child #1      3
```

After adding the new element on the front-end, I am getting only the parent's ID to which this new element belongs to.

Let's see the example. I'd like to add the new element to the `Child #1` that has `ID` equals to `3` and `ParentID` equals to `1`.

From the front-end, I get only the `ID` value (e.g. `3` in our example above). When I'd like to insert the new element into the table, I need to set this element the right `ParentID`. What query should I use to achieve this? Please, take a look at my query below:

```
INSERT INTO `tree` (`ID`, `Name`, `ParentID`) 
VALUES (11, "The new element", "and here I'd like to give this new element the ParentID of the element with ID equals to 3");
```

Comment: what is your criteria? if you don't know the parent how should we guess it? if parent id is 3 insert 3 then, if you want to use parent of element with `id=3` so the 3 record is a sibling of the element you want insert?

Comment: But we have the ID of the element, that has parent, that we need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `insert select` statement:

```
insert into `tree`(`ID`, `Name`, `ParentID`)
select 11, "Inserted Element", `ParentID`
from `tree` where `ID` = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually this needs to be done via the application level however in the same query you can use `insert into .. select from`

```
insert into `tree`(`ID`, `Name`, `ParentID`)
select 
11,
"Inserted Element",
ParentID
from(
 select ParentID from tree where ID = 3
)x
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this syntax is legal with your DB, but try something like this

```
INSERT INTO `tree`(`ID`, `Name`, `ParentID`) VALUES (11, "Inserted Element", (SELECT ParentID FROM tree 
WHERE id = 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c574d/1

```
INSERT INTO tree (id, name, parentID)
  SELECT 11, 'Inserted Element', parentID 
  FROM tree t 
  WHERE t.id = 3;
```